# Show that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(O_n)=m(E)$ when $E$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Below is an attempt at a proof of the following problem. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

---

Let $E$ be a set and $O_n = \{x: d(x, E) < \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Show

- If $E$ is compact then $m(E) = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(O_n)$.
- This is false for $E$ closed and unbounded or $E$ open and bounded.

Note that all sets are real and measurable refers to Lebesgue measurable.

---

**Suppose $E$ is compact.** Then $m(E) < \infty$. Also, since each $O_n$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $m(O_n) < \infty$. If either of the following is true, we have that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(O_n)=m(E)$:

$O_n \nearrow E$

$O_n \searrow E$

Now  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} O_n = \{ x:d(x,E) = 0\}$.

That is, $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_n \iff \exists n> \frac{1}{\epsilon},\ n \in \mathbb{N} \iff x\in \{x \mid d(x,E) =0\}$.

Then we have that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_n = E$ and $O_n \searrow E$. Thus $ \ m(E) = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(O_n)$.

**Suppose $E$ is closed and unbounded.** Let $E = \{(x,y): y = 2 \}$ and $O_n = \{(x,y): d(x,E) < \frac{1}{n}\}$.

Since $E$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $m(E) = 0$.

Also, since the measure of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is its volume, $m(O_n) = \left| O_n \right| = \infty$, since the rectangle $O_n$ is unbounded.

It is therefore apparent that $m(E) \not = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(O_n)$.

**Suppose $E$ is open and bounded.**
Let $E=(0,1)$ and $O_n = \{x \mid d(x,E) < \frac{1}{n}\}$.

$\mathbb{R}-E$ is closed and $O_n \in \mathbb{R}-E$.

Since $\mathbb{R}-E$ contains all its limit points $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}O_n = O \in \mathbb{R}-E$.

Thus $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(O_n) \neq m(E)$.

Comment: How's that? What is needed then?

Comment: Nope, you definitely need both of those assumptions. Your first two examples are correct, but your open bounded example doesn't work. If $E=(0,1)$ then $O_n = (-1/n, 1+1/n)$, so $m(O_n) = 1+2/n \to 1 = m(E)$. You're gonna need a more abstract example than that. Try for an open subset of $(0,1)$ which contains a dense subset but doesn't have full Lebesgue measure.

Comment: As mentioned in Shalop's comment and in zhw's answer: Modify the construction of the Cantor  set by removing open middle 4ths instead of 3rds, giving  giving $C=\bar  C \subset S [0,1].$  Then $ E=[0,1]\backslash C$ is open and $m(E)=1/2.$ But $\bar E=[0,1]$ so for any $n \in N,$ every $x\in [0,1]$ is within distance $1/n$ of a member of  $E,$ so $O_n\supset [0,1]$ so $m(O_n)\geq 1.$

Comment: @Shalop Thx, good counter to my poor example.

Comment: @user254665 This is great and I think it would suffice to take intervals of $\epsilon >0$ around the rationals.

Comment: Yes, If you put an open interval of length $2^{-n}d$  around the $n$th rational,  the union of the intervals has measure at most $d$, but $O_n=R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example for $E$ open and bounded is not correct. I really can't tell what you are doing, but it should be clear that $m((0,1)) = \lim_{n\to \infty}m(O_n)$ in this case.

Hint for an example: Let $E$ be an open dense subset of $(0,1)$ such that $m(E)<1/2.$,

Answer (score 0):

I refer to your three settings as (1), (2), and (3).

(1) What you write here is confusing. You only have to prove that $\bigcap_nO_n = E$. Clearly, $E\subset\bigcap_nO_n$. Now show that $\bigcap_n O_n\subset E$.

(2) This is a correct counterexample.

(3) The counterexample is false. You have $\bigcap_n O_n = [0,1]$ and thus $\lim m(O_n) = m([0,1]) = m(E) + m(\{0,1\}) = m(E)$. I think that the claim is false anyway. We should have $\lim m(O_n) = m(E)$ for bounded and open $E$.

Comment: Nope, there are some easy counterexamples for (3).

Comment: Alright. I just saw your example above. I forgot that there are such strange open sets containing all rationals but which can be arbitrarily small in measure. It's just hard to imagine.

Comment: @Friedrich Philipp. It's because $Q$ is countable. If $R\supset  F= \{x_n:n\in N\}$ and $d>0$ let $S_d= \cup \{(-2^{-n}d+x_n,2^{-n}d+x_n) :n\in N\}.$ Then $S_d$ is open and $F\supset S_d$ and $m(S_d)\leq \sum_{n\in N} 2.2^{-n}e=2 e.$

Answer (score -1):

This is a consequence of the fact that Lebesgue measure is a regular measure.

This means that, if $E$ is measurable, then 
$$
\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(U): E\subset U\,\,\&\,\,U\,\,\,\text{open}\}.
$$ 
So, if $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists a $U$ open, $E\subset U$ and $\mu(U)-\mu(E)<\varepsilon)$. If 
$$
d=\mathrm{dist}\,(E,U^c),
$$
and $1/n<d$, then $E\subset O_n\subset U$.

Comment: This does not work when  $E$ is open and bounded  as we may have $U=E\ne \phi$ so $d(E,U^c)=0$ and  $O_n\not \subset U.$